# Spring boot JPA nnotationException: No identifier specified for entity, while having proper id

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have such DAO:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "questionnaire_answer")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class QuestionnaireAnswer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
```

and repository:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questionnaire_answer")
public interface QuestionaireRepository extends CrudRepository<QuestionnaireAnswer, UUID> {
```

sql:

```
CREATE TABLE questionnaire_answer (
    id varchar(36) PRIMARY KEY,
...
)
```

but still I see an error:

> AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:

what can I do wrong here ?

> Blockquote

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the data type? In some db/jpa implementations, UUID is mapped as BINARY. Have you checked how it works with an string?

Comment: @SJuan76 thats weird, coz I have other tables with identical id varchar(36) :) I will try with binary

Answer (score 1):

eh I am so blind, stupid mistake

@Repository should be in QuestionaireRepository
but I put there table and entity :)) it was end of my day..
today I realized what had happened.